# <col class="a specified background color"> ignored

Tags: html, css

Added in edit: I resolved the problem by adding

```
table, tr, th, td
{
background-color : transparent ; /* for coloring columns */
... }
```

### to the initial conditions because I read (somewhere, after asking the question) that one could not color a column unless it was initially transparent. I cannot now provide a reference for this belief, but it worked for me.

The following code works fine in the w3schools TryIt, producing a gray header and red and green columns -- but in my table [lacking the initial 'transparent'] it grays the header row but leaves the columns white.

The css:

```
.bggra {background-color: #e0e0e0;}
.bgred {background-color: #ffe8e8;}
.bggrn {background-color: #d0ead0;}
```

The html:

```
<colgroup>
<col class="bgred">
<col class="bggrn">
</colgroup>
...
<thead>
<tr class="bggra">
```

Firefox 'Inspector' shows 20 rules for the first 'red' box of the table, with the background-color of the initial 'table' rule not crossed out. It says nothing about .bgred , and mentions col only in connection with {unicode-bidi: isolate;}. (I am a newbie at Inspector!)

Since it works in TryIt, it seems that the earlier comment "There should be a syntax available to allow colgroup and col settings to override those of tr and td values. – cartbeforehorse Oct 21 '12 at 10:55" had some effect -- but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: can you please show us your code...you can use jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: @Ashishsah beat me to it

Comment: let him provide the code

Comment: I think I get it after seeing below answer...he wants the header row to be grey and the rows underneath to be red for col 1, green for col 2.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bggra {background-color: #e0e0e0;}
.bgred {background-color: #ffe8e8;}
.bggrn {background-color: #d0ead0;}
```

```html
<table>

<colgroup>
<col class="bgred">
<col class="bggrn">
</colgroup>
<tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
    
  </tr>

</table>
```

It works fine for me.

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .bggra {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }
    .bgred {
    background-color: #ffe8e8;
    }
    .bggrn {
    background-color: #d0ead0;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table>

    <colgroup>
    <col class="bgred">
    <col class="bggrn">
    </colgroup>
    <tr class="bggra">
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>

      </tr>

    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```